# JavaScript event inheritance

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm using a list to build a simple nav menu, that shows when you hover and hides when you leave it.  I want the menu (ul) to appear when the a tag is hovered, and only disappear when mousing out of the entire div.  However, the code below is hitting the `mouseout` when every tag is moused out, not just the div tag.  I assume each child tag is inheriting the event, but how do I get around that?

```
<div id="Div1" onmouseout="alert('out')">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="#" onmouseover="alert('over')">Show Others</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse over/out events can act a bit weird, and the worst part of it all is that it varies between browsers. What I recommend you do is to use a JavaScript framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which has cross-browser handling of `mouseover` and `mouseout`. Even better, it has `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, which are special events that are sure to only trigger once per mouse entering/leaving of an element, even if it has child elements.

See [demo of mouseenter/mouseleave events in jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseenter#demo).